# Horizontal Timeline with Items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a type of horizontal timeline in which items that are fetched via JS using an API are displayed. Initially 3 elements should be displayed, further elements will be shown afterwards by means of a slider. There should be a horizontal line in the middle and the items should alternately start one below the line and then one above the line. The height of the items is dynamic and is determined by the content. The width should be 33% minus some margin. See picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4FyX.png

I cant get it working because in my current solution the items above the line are cut at like 5rem hight and i have no idea how to fix that using absolute positioned items. Here is my current code:

The class itm-timeline-wrapper draws the horizontal line and the class itm-timeline currently is the item which is placed above or below the line. This is how it looks like, there is much more content in the items but as you can see the items getting cut on top and bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvmyZ.png Hope someone can help me fix this issue. Im also open for other attempts like not using absolute positioned items.

```css
.timeline-items {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 250px 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  display: flex;
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f45b69;
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper:nth-child(odd) .itm-timeline {
  top: -16px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper:nth-child(odd) .itm-timeline:before {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper:nth-child(even) .itm-timeline {
  top: calc(-100% + 16px);
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper:nth-child(even) .itm-timeline:before {
  top: -8px;
  border-width: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

.timeline-items .itm-timeline-wrapper .itm-timeline {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 1.5rem);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  white-space: normal;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="timeline-items">
            <div class="itm-timeline-wrapper">
              <div class="itm-timeline">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </div>
              </div>
               <div class="itm-timeline-wrapper">
              <div class="itm-timeline"> consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </div>
              </div>
               <div class="itm-timeline-wrapper">
              <div class="itm-timeline">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***EDIT:***
After it worked well with Wongjn's solution, I implemented splidejs as a slider to be able to slide through the items https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#perpage.. In order to use Splidejs efficiently, the correct number of items that are displayed at the same time must be specified using JS. Since I want to display 3 items, I have to use the option "perPage: 3". This automatically gives each itm-timeline a width of 33.33% through Splidejs. However, since I have already used grid-auto-columns: 33% to divide the items in Wongjn's solution, which has worked so far, the perPage: 3 option destroys the layout. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with grids. A grid-auto-columns: 100% doesn't help or breaks the layout even more. Since I use an external library, I can't customize the stack fiddle properly either. I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Please convert your SCSS to CSS and add a Stack Snippet to the question.

Comment: Oh yes sure, i added a snipped

Answer (score 1):

You could consider some sort of grid layout:

```css
.timeline-items {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 33%;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 3px max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.itm-timeline {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.itm-timeline:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  align-self: end;
}

.itm-timeline:nth-child(even) {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  border-top: 3px solid;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-items">
  <div class="itm-timeline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque in purus ac cursus. Donec vel consectetur magna, in posuere elit. Mauris laoreet ullamcorper pellentesque. Nam pharetra sapien mi, in consequat nulla congue eget. Morbi vehicula
    ac nibh ut vehicula. Donec id nisi tristique, commodo velit non, scelerisque odio. Quisque id congue elit. Nunc et semper risus. Duis sit amet mi ut purus rutrum lobortis non quis lectus. Vivamus in erat porta, laoreet felis non, volutpat ex. Sed
    sed urna luctus arcu imperdiet suscipit vitae et tellus. Quisque a eros volutpat, vehicula odio vitae, hendrerit tortor.
  </div>
  <div class="itm-timeline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque in purus ac cursus. Donec vel consectetur magna, in posuere elit. Mauris laoreet ullamcorper pellentesque. Nam pharetra sapien mi, in consequat nulla congue eget. Morbi vehicula
  </div>
  <div class="itm-timeline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque in purus ac cursus. Donec vel consectetur magna, in posuere elit. Mauris laoreet ullamcorper pellentesque. Nam pharetra sapien mi, in consequat nulla congue eget. Morbi vehicula
    ac nibh ut vehicula. Donec id nisi tristique, commodo velit non, scelerisque odio. Quisque id congue elit. Nunc et semper risus. Duis sit amet mi ut purus rutrum lobortis non quis lectus. Vivamus in erat porta, laoreet felis non, volutpat ex. Sed
  </div>
  <div class="itm-timeline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque in purus ac cursus. Donec vel consectetur magna, in posuere elit. Mauris laoreet ullamcorper pellentesque. Nam pharetra sapien mi, in consequat nulla congue eget. Morbi vehicula
    ac nibh ut vehicula. Donec id nisi tristique, commodo velit non, scelerisque odio. Quisque id congue elit. Nunc et semper risus. Duis sit amet mi ut purus rutrum lobortis non quis lectus. Vivamus in erat porta, laoreet felis non, volutpat ex. Sed
    sed urna luctus arcu imperdiet suscipit vitae et tellus. Quisque a eros volutpat, vehicula odio vitae, hendrerit tortor.
  </div>
</div>
```

- Set `grid-auto-columns: 33%` so that each item is 33% width.
- Set `grid-auto-flow: column` so that items flow horizontally across the grid layout.
- Set `grid-template-rows: max-content 3px max-content` so there is an odd number of rows, so that when an item occupies two grid row tracks, they cannot "fit" and thus will continue horizontally. The `3px` middle row track would be for the timeline line. We use `max-content` so that the row tracks that will have content will be as tall as the tallest element.
- Odd `.itm-timeline` elements fill the top two grid row tracks, aligned to the bottom, with a bottom border for the timeline.
- Even `.itm-timeline` elements fill the bottom two grid row tracks, aligned to the top, with a top border for the timeline.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me out a lot. I now try to use splide as a slider and run into some problems with your solution which worked fine before. Maybe you can take a look into my edit. Thanks in advance!